# How to send Client Hello over http proxy tunnel

Tags: go, ssl, proxy

I have a client which will establish TLS connection to backend service.
There are two kind of scenarios that I encounter.

1. Direct network: client--->server
   In this environment, The client connect directly to server as below code.

```
   var d tls.Dialer
   //...
   d.Config = &tls.Config{
        //...
   }
   //...
   c1 := d.Dial("tcp", addr)
```

2. Proxy network: client--->proxy--->server
   In this environment, The client is behind a http proxy, client need leverage proxy http tunnel to forward traffic between client and server.
   I use `golang.org/x/net/proxy` in client to connect proxy, as proxy is http proxy, client should use net.Dialer to connect proxy via tcp.

```
   dailer, err := proxy.FromURL(proxy, &net.Dialer{
        Timeout:   TCP_CONNECT_TIMEOUT,
        KeepAlive: TCP_KEEPALIVE_TIMEOUT,
    })
   c2 := dailer.Dial("tcp", addr)
```

In case1, client start a TLS connection, in network traffic packets, client trigger TCP connection, after 3 way handshakes, client send `Client Hello` to server.

In case2, client first use TCP to connect http proxy (ex, 10.0.0.1:8080), next, send `CONNECT` to proxy, then proxy return `Connection Established`, however, client do **NOT** send `Client Hello` to server.

For case2, I do not know how and where to implement to send `Client Hello` in client?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searched go doc, I found the solution, Hope useful for later comer with similar problem.

In `tls`, there is a function [Client](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#Client) which can construct from exist net.Conn, then use [Handshake](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#Conn.Handshake)

```
tlsConn := tls.Client(conn, &tls.Config{
    Certificates:       []tls.Certificate{*cert},
    InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    ServerName:         sni,
    ClientAuth:         tls.RequestClientCert,
})
err = tlsConn.Handshake()
```